# How to annotate types of multiple inheritance?

Tags: python, typing, mypy

I want to annotate types of multiple inheritance. For example:

```py
class Foo:
    ...

class BarMixin:
    ...

def f(obj: "class inheriting both (BarMixin, Foo)"): # I want to know how to annotate `obj`
    ...
```

Comment: `Union` and `Intersection` may be of interest. Unfortunately, the latter doesn't exist (yet?).

Comment: I found issue tracker for `Intersection` https://github.com/python/typing/issues/213

Comment: I found `Union` can deceive mypy, but I feel uncomfortable because `Union` is "or".

Comment: @Yohei Union is not correct here

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Yes, Union is "or", but what I want is Intersection, which is "and"